# CrtDebug Stackoverflow?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, debugging, crt

I'm getting an access violation I can't quite debug.

I seem to be getting some kind of recursive error inside of the CRT call `_CrtCheckMemory`.

The following is the call stack (bottom -> top), where the `...` is just removed repeated messages.

```
msvcr100d.dll!__chkstk()    Unknown
msvcr100d.dll!_VCrtDbgReportA(int nRptType, const char * szFile, int nLine, const char * szModule, const char * szFormat, char * arglist) Line 252  C
msvcr100d.dll!_CrtDbgReportV(int nRptType, const char * szFile, int nLine, const char * szModule, const char * szFormat, char * arglist) Line 242   C
msvcr100d.dll!_CrtDbgReport(int nRptType, const char * szFile, int nLine, const char * szModule, const char * szFormat, ...) Line 258   C
msvcr100d.dll!_CrtCheckMemory() Line 1817   C++
msvcr100d.dll!_heap_alloc_dbg_impl(unsigned __int64 nSize, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine, int * errno_tmp) Line 383 C++
msvcr100d.dll!_nh_malloc_dbg_impl(unsigned __int64 nSize, int nhFlag, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine, int * errno_tmp) Line 239  C++
msvcr100d.dll!_calloc_dbg_impl(unsigned __int64 nNum, unsigned __int64 nSize, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine, int * errno_tmp) Line 601  C++
msvcr100d.dll!_getptd_noexit() Line 470 C
msvcr100d.dll!_XcptFilter(unsigned long xcptnum, _EXCEPTION_POINTERS * pxcptinfoptrs) Line 202  C
msvcr100d.dll!_callthreadstartex$filt$0() Line 316  C
msvcr100d.dll!__C_specific_handler(_EXCEPTION_RECORD * ExceptionRecord, void * EstablisherFrame, _CONTEXT * ContextRecord, _DISPATCHER_CONTEXT * DispatcherContext) C
ntdll.dll!0000000077989d0d()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!00000000779791af()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!00000000779b1278()    Unknown
msvcr100d.dll!__chkstk()    Unknown
...
msvcr100d.dll!_VCrtDbgReportA(int nRptType, const char * szFile, int nLine, const char * szModule, const char * szFormat, char * arglist) Line 298  C
msvcr100d.dll!_CrtDbgReportV(int nRptType, const char * szFile, int nLine, const char * szModule, const char * szFormat, char * arglist) Line 242   C
msvcr100d.dll!_CrtDbgReport(int nRptType, const char * szFile, int nLine, const char * szModule, const char * szFormat, ...) Line 258   C
msvcr100d.dll!_CrtCheckMemory() Line 1817   C++
msvcr100d.dll!_heap_alloc_dbg_impl(unsigned __int64 nSize, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine, int * errno_tmp) Line 383 C++
msvcr100d.dll!_nh_malloc_dbg_impl(unsigned __int64 nSize, int nhFlag, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine, int * errno_tmp) Line 239  C++
msvcr100d.dll!_calloc_dbg_impl(unsigned __int64 nNum, unsigned __int64 nSize, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine, int * errno_tmp) Line 601  C++
msvcr100d.dll!_getptd_noexit() Line 470 C
msvcr100d.dll!_errno() Line 280 C
msvcr100d.dll!_VCrtDbgReportA(int nRptType, const char * szFile, int nLine, const char * szModule, const char * szFormat, char * arglist) Line 298  C
msvcr100d.dll!_CrtDbgReportV(int nRptType, const char * szFile, int nLine, const char * szModule, const char * szFormat, char * arglist) Line 242   C
msvcr100d.dll!_CrtDbgReport(int nRptType, const char * szFile, int nLine, const char * szModule, const char * szFormat, ...) Line 258   C
msvcr100d.dll!_CrtCheckMemory() Line 1817   C++
msvcr100d.dll!_free_dbg_nolock(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line 1288   C++
msvcr100d.dll!_free_dbg(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line 1265  C++
msvcr100d.dll!_freefls(void * data) Line 622    C
msvcr100d.dll!_freeptd(_tiddata * ptd) Line 683 C
msvcr100d.dll!_endthreadex(unsigned int retcode) Line 365   C
msvcr100d.dll!_callthreadstartex() Line 315 C
msvcr100d.dll!_threadstartex(void * ptd) Line 297   C
kernel32.dll!000000007729652d() Unknown
ntdll.dll!000000007798c521()    Unknown
```

Any idea what might be causing this or advice on how I might go about debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that's a bit tragic.  It is trying to generate a diagnostic to tell you that the heap is corrupted.  The reporting code tries to obtain the value of *errno* in order to display it, but that's a static CRT variable that gets allocated on demand.  So it allocates memory.  Which dies, the heap is corrupted.  Which triggers a diagnostic to tell you that the heap is corrupted.  You can guess the rest, this goes on and on until it runs out of stack.

One workaround is to add this bit of code to the start of main (or the thread):

```
 int dummy = errno;
```

so the CRT allocates memory before the heap gets corrupted.  You'll still have to find the cause of the corruption.

Comment: I've tried running appverifier and enabling full page heaps, which break the visual studio debugger on some stuff. However, whenever I get this specific crash, it doesn't break on anything (other than what I've posted). Suggestions?

Comment: The "some stuff" the debugger breaks on might be code accessing the invalid page that full page heap places after your allocation.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your main problem is you have corrupted your memory and now when program want to exit, it want to free its internal allocated memory( memory that used to store per thread data ), and since you are using debug version it will check its memory and understand the failure and start to show an assertion window, now when it want to show its assertion window it need to allocate some memory and use memory allocation routines (`malloc` witch will be converted to `malloc_dbg` in this case) to allocate its required memory and `malloc_dbg` check memory status and understand your memory corruption and try to show an assertion window again and this procedure will be repeated. please check your dynamic memory allocation (and even check statically defined array for override) to solve your memory corruption and stack overflow will be solved automatically